# Audio WMA incorrectly reported as video/x-ms-wma

Tags: javascript, validation, wma

Having to handle audio WMA files as part of an upload script but I've run across a really annoying bug with the file type.

I need to only allow audio, NOT video but it seems that all WMA files have the type of :

```
video/x-ms-wma
```

Whether they contain video or not.

I was expecting :

```
audio/x-ms-wma
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case and it means that I can't validate the type correctly with javascript as :

```
file.type.match('audio.*')
```

Which is obviously failing here.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was a Chrome bug in my case.

Solved using regex: `file.type.match(/audio|wma/)`

This matches the text `audio` **or** `wma`.